# How to plot lines for the count data in R?

Tags: r

I have data frame like this:

```
frame <- data.frame("AGE" = seq(18,44,1), 
                   "GROUP1"= c(83,101,159,185,212,276,330,293,330,356,370,325,264,274,214,229,227,154,132,121,83,69,57,32,16,17,8),
                   "GROUP2"= c(144,210,259,329,391,421,453,358,338,318,270,258,207,186,173,135,106,92,74,56,41,31,25,13,16,5,8))
```

I want to plot AGE in X-axis and value of GROUP1 and GROUP2 in the Y-axis in the same plot with different colors. And the values should be joined by a smoothened line.

As a first part, I melted the data frame and plotted:

```
melt <- melt(frame, id.vars = "AGE")
melt <- melt[order(melt$AGE),]
plot(melt$AGE, melt$value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

newframe <- frame %>% gather("variable","value",-AGE)

ggplot(newframe, aes(x=AGE, y=value, color=variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]

You could use `geom_line()` to get lines between the points, but it feels better to use `geom_smooth()` here. `geom_area` gives you a shaded area under the lines, but we need to change `color` to `fill`.

```
ggplot(newframe, aes(x=AGE, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_area()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `matplot`

```
matplot(`row.names<-`(as.matrix(frame[-1]), frame[,1]), 
    ylab='value',type = "l", xlab = "AGE",col = c("red", "blue"), pch = 1)
legend("topright", inset = .05, legend = c("GROUP1", "GROUP2"), 
        pch = 1, col = c("red", "blue"), horiz = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to shade the areas under the lines with colors?

Comment: @technOslerphile  It could be possible but that was not the original question

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(meltdf,aes(x=AGE,y=value,colour=variable,group=variable)) + geom_line()
```